# Post request 2D integer array as raw data

Tags: android, rest, post, request, httprequest

I need to send a post request to an URL with `Content-type: application/json` and with raw data such as:

`[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

I have a 2D array consist of integers, I want to send that array as raw data. It should not be a string so I cannot use gson. I tried to use `HttpURLConnection` without success. What's the way to go?

Comment: Could you share your non-successful code?

Comment: No one will come here with the code if you don't show some effort on your side.